# ¿obtener valor de input en una tabla HTML que se genera dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo una tabla HTML que lleno dinamicamente con una tabla de una BD, a cada fila que devuelve le agrego un input text para que agregue cierta información para cada fila, una fila no tiene nada que ver con las demás, actualmente ya le he colocado nombre diferente a cada input de la tabla, cuando me posiciono en el input de una fila, me debe obtener un id que esta pintado en la tabla para validar esa información con ajax, el problema que tengo es que tengo el código para obtener ese valor pero solo colocando el id del input especifico y no de forma general para cualquier input que yo seleccione, ¿Como puedo hacer esa función de JS para que pueda obtener ese valor para cualquier input?

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //El id de los input comienza con numeroFac-0, numeroFac-1...
        $('#numeroFac-0').on('focus', function () {
            var hola = $(this).parent().parent();
            hola.children().each(function () {
                var celdas = hola.children();
                $('#txtNombre').val($(celdas[0]).text());
                $('#test').val($(celdas[1]).text());
                $('#txtFechaa').val($(celdas[3]).text());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

este es mi tabla o el html

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Cliente</th>                    
                    <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Nombre</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Total compras</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Total a comisionar</th>                    
                    <th style="text-align:center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Alcance %</th>
                    <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Monto $</th>
                    <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Concepto</th>
                    <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Ingresar Factura</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @Code If consultaComisiones.Count > 0 Then End Code
                
                @Code For Each item1 In consultaComisiones End Code
                        
                    <tr>
                        
                        @Code If item1("Alcance") >= "80" And (item1("NIVEL_PRECIO") = "DAF B" Or item1("NIVEL_PRECIO") = "DAF C") Then End Code
                           
                        <td>@item1("Cliente") <input type="text" id="numeroCliente" name="numeroCliente" value="@item1("Cliente")" /></td> 
                        <td>@item1("Nombre") <input type="text" id="nombreCliente" name="nombreCliente" value="@item1("Nombre")" /></td>                        
                        <td style="text-align:center">@item1("total_compras") <input type="text" id="totalCompras" name="totalCompras" value="@item1("total_compras")" /> </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">@item1("total_parad") <input type="text" id="totalComisionar" name="totalComisionar" value="@item1("total_parad")" /> </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">@item1("Alcance") % <input type="text" id="alcance" name="alcance" value="@item1("Alcance")" /> </td>
                        <td>@Format(item1("Monto"),"C") <input type="text" id="monto" name="monto" value="@item1("Monto")" /> </td>
                        <td>Permanencia Amigo Chip 60 Dias(@item1("MES") @item1("ANIO"))@item1("total_parad") -lineas <input type="text" id="concepto" name="concepto" value="Permanencia Amigo Chip 60 Dias(@item1("MES") @item1("ANIO"))@item1("total_parad") -lineas" /> </td>                          
                        <td><input type="text" id="numeroFactura-@i"   /></td>    
                         @Code   i = i + 1
                              End If End Code                
                                        
                    </tr>

                  @Code Next End Code
                    <tr>                        
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><center><button type="button" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar</button></center></td>
                    </tr>
                
               @Code Else End Code
                    <tr>                        
                        <td colspan="8" >
                           <span style="color:red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No existen resultados con los parametros de búsqueda que elegiste... </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                    
              @Code End If End Code
            </tbody>                
        </table>
        </form>
        <span class="text-success">Registros encontrados.: <span class="badge">@i</span></span>
        <div id="resultados" ></div>
```

Comment: Sería muy útil que agregues la estructura del html

Comment: listo arriba esta @md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for(var b in a){
  var c = a[b];
if(typeof c=="object"){
  c.onclick = function (){
     console.log(this.id);
  }
}
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input id="uno" value="a" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="dos" value="b" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="tres" value="c" /></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias amigo! justo lo que necesito =)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que indicas en el código, parece que lo que quieres es aplicar el controlador del evento a los `input` cuyo id comience con `numeroFac-` (p.e.: numeroFac-0, numeroFac-1, numeroFac-2...) en lugar de a todos los `input`.

Para ello puedes utilizar un selector sólo para los id's que comiencen por una cadena en concreto, el formato sería el siguiente: `[atributo^='valor']`. Eso seleccionará todos los elementos cuyo atributo comience por la cadena valor. En tu caso quieres que se seleccionen los `input` cuyo id empiece con numeroFac-, así que lo que harías sería algo como esto: `input[id^='numeroFac-']`. Que en tu código quedaría así:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //El id de los input comienza con numeroFac-0, numeroFac-1...
        $("input[id^='numeroFac-']").on('focus', function () {
            var hola = $(this).parent().parent();
            hola.children().each(function () {
                var celdas = hola.children();
                $('#txtNombre').val($(celdas[0]).text());
                $('#test').val($(celdas[1]).text());
                $('#txtFechaa').val($(celdas[3]).text());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar

el siguiente codigo

$(this).closest('table').attr('id')

closest

Este método lo emplearemos cuando necesitemos obtener un determinado objeto (en este caso la información de una  table, luego con attr buscaremos el atributo "id"

claro que este código funcionada dentro de each()

Saludos.